# Is it possible to 'reopen' closed DB in PouchDB

Tags: javascript, react-native, pouchdb

Is it possible to close connection to PouchDb using `db.close()` and then **reopen the same db connection again**?

I have an app in which each user can be assigned to multiple groups, and each group has it's own DB.
To allow users to switch groups (and DBs) I want to close the current DB - the one that user has just left - in order to avoid memory leaks.
Problem is when user returns to the first group - it's closed and the replication is not working. How can I 'reopen' it?

I can't find an option for reopening a DB anywhere in the documentation.
I did try to make a new PouchDB instance, by using:

```
new PouchDB(uniqueId)
```

but my previously working replication didn't react anymore after closing the DB.

What am I missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You re-open a database exactly the same way you opened it the first time:

```
var db = new PouchDB("dbname");
```

You'll have to re-start any replications at that point.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to reopen or reset a closed/destroyed database in the same variable instantiation, you can recall the constructor. Note, it is definitely not good practice to call constructors again, but this is the only way I could get PouchDb to cooperate on this issue. I use this to reset my database in between tests while still being able to reuse the same variable.

```js
export async function resetTestDb(
  db: PouchDB.Database & {
    __opts?: PouchDB.Configuration.DatabaseConfiguration;
    _destroyed?: boolean;
    _closed?: boolean;
  }
): Promise<PouchDB.Database> {
  await db.destroy().catch(() => {});

  // nasty hack to reopen closed database
  delete db._destroyed;
  delete db._closed;
  return db.constructor(db.name, db.__opts);
}
```